# The app requested an invalid permission- Facebook api

Tags: android, facebook, firebase-authentication

```
facebook:onError     SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349013 [message]: The app requested
an invalid permission. [extra]:
```

This is the error. I am using Firebase Authentication facebook login and the following permissions with this code snippet.

```
loginButton.setPermissions("email", "public_profile","user_friends");
```

Comment: I'm having this issue, did you solve it?

Comment: Hi guys, everything was working fine just yesterday on my app, and today I just got this, how did you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

I originally had 'public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email' permissions, and as I don't really need user_friends, just removed it and my app is working again, what puzzles me is that it was working fine just yesterday, and the auth code haven been changed, also checked for changes on facebook page, but could not find anything

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference

> Every permission below requires App Review except for email.

At least, `user_friends` seems to require App Review.